# Google Bigquery Standard SQL - How to: If hit contains sku then select hitnumber else max(hitnumber)?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

```
select
  concat(fullvisitorid,cast(visitid as string)) as unique_session_id
  ,case
    when h.item.productSku is not null then h.hitNumber
    else max(h.hitnumber)
   end
  ,h.item.transactionid
  ,h.item.itemrevenue/pow(10,6)
  ,h.item.productSku
from `myproject.mydataset.ga_sessions_20180101`, unnest(hits) as h
group by 1
```

Looking at case statement above (line 3)

1. How do I return that hitnumber where the productsku is populated 
   otherwise return the max hitnumber and then group this by the unique_session_id?
2. How to filter out transactionid's that contain '_ABC' at the same time?

Comment: it is not clear - what aggregation you expect when grouping by unique_session_id? also you cannot group just by unique_session_id! how about transactionid, productSku and what aggregation to do for itemrevenue? i need to revisit your question and provide more details along with input and expected output example

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest doing the grouping and finding the max hit number in a subquery. If you are going to use an aggregate function like `MAX()` in the select clause, then you need to group on or have aggregate functions for the other fields in the select. It can be useful to do aggregate sub-queries using common table expressions.

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitid AS string)) AS unique_session_id,
    h.hitNumber,
    h.item.transactionid,
    h.item.itemrevenue/POW(10,6) AS itemRevenue,
    h.item.productSku
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS h
),
max_hits AS (
  SELECT
    unique_session_id,
    MAX(hitNumber) AS max_hit_number
  FROM data
  GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT
  d.unique_session_id,
  CASE
    WHEN d.productSku IS NOT NULL THEN d.hitNumber
    ELSE m.max_hit_number 
  END,
  d.transactionid,
  d.itemrevenue,
  d.productSku
FROM
  data AS d JOIN max_hits AS m
ON d.unique_session_id = m.unique_session_id
```